# Disallow entire directory for all the search engines from robots.txt file

Tags: robots.txt

Can anyone guide me how to create robots.TXT file for the following URLs or directory:

Original URL which I want to do index in search engines:

```
book2park.com/
book2park.com/locations.php
```

But the following URLs (almost all the pages) I found in Google database which I want to disallow permanently from all the search engines:

```
lawnchair.book2park.com/
lawnchair.book2park.com/locations.php
```

Basically "Lawnchair" comes before the start of every URL.

Comment: What did you try? And do you really want to disallow only `/` and `locations.php` on `lawnchair.book2park.com`, no other URLs?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,

I just want to index www.book2park.com
I never want to index this http://lawnchair.book2park.com/

Please let me know how i could disallow this form robots.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

A given robots.txt file applies only to the exact subdomain it was loaded from. In other words, the following robots.txt file:

```
http://sub1.example.com/robots.txt
```

can only control crawling of:

```
http://sub1.example.com/...
```

It can not control crawling of:

```
http://example.com/...
http://sub2.example.com/...
http://sub.sub1.example.com/...
```

The solution is to add a separate robots.txt file for each subdomain. So, on http://lawnchair.book2park.com/robots.txt you could block everything:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

and on http://book2park.com/robots.txt you could allow everything:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

(or you could just not have a robots.txt file on the main domain)